# How to loop through the inner elements within 'document.querySelector'

Tags: javascript, html, devtools

I am using chrome devtools to inspect html. I have this code where I apply `querySelector` for inner elements:

```
var x = document.querySelectorAll(".search__results-list li");
var myarray = []
for (var i=0; i<x.length; i++){
    const href = x[i].querySelector('.ahchor[href]');
    const text = x[i].querySelector('.text-field');

    myarray.push([href, text]);
};
```

The `querySelector` does not exists on `x[i]`, getting an error `Uncaught TypeError: [...].querySelector is not a function` how to fix that?

here is the html sample, in reality there is a lot of li's wthin:

```
<ul class="search__results-list">
  <li class="search__result-container">
    <div class="search-result">
      <div class="search-result__item">
        <div class="search-result_block">
          <div class="center">
            <a class="ahchor" href="somesite.com/a">
              <div>
                <div class="wrapper">
                  <div class="entity">
                    <div class="text-field">content here</div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Show us html. And you won't get text and href strings like that, but only elements so you know.

Comment: Add `console.log()` calls to see what you have. But I still doubt this is the code you have.

Comment: It shouldn't throw the error. Are you certain you load the html before the script (the elements exist)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code syntax errors

Should be:

```
var x = document.querySelectorAll(".search__results-list li");
var myarray = []
for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    const href = x[i].querySelector('.ahchor[href]');
    const text = x[i].querySelector('.text-field');

    myarray.push([href, text]);
};
```

This code should work if you wrote classes correctly and accordingly to your html

---

You can check this code even in console  there, works fine. But I didn't find wrappers with 2 elements and use .m6 twice

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w0s2n.png)

I used the Chrome development tool to achieve this. I found that according to your code, you can achieve logic without error. You can run the code several times.

Comment: this is interesting, that what I am trying to achieve

Comment: querySelector has huge browsers compatibility. Even chrome v1 https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector

Comment: Haha, yes. At the beginning, I also thought that queryselector was very compatible, but I can't remember which version started to be compatible. Now I know, I said the compatibility of browsers for the sake of safety.